# How I can find MouseClick or GotFocus event in PivotItem.?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, pivotitem

Hello How I can find GotFocus event into the PivotItem I had tired with GalaSoft Interaction with Triger and EventName="GotFocus" but it is not fired can anybody help me to find the PivioItem Event.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the pivot item gets focus upon cliking any control placed inside that pivot item.

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="item1">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowMessageCommand}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox Height="100"
                             Width="200"/>
                    <Button Height="100"
                            Width="200" />
                </Grid>
            </controls:PivotItem>
```

This code works for me. the pivot item get focus upon clicking the button or the text box.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: this is working but I have to click inside the Pivot Cotrol is there any way to directly when we click to the Pivot Control's Header or else we can move the pivot control using mouse then it will be fired.? Thank you.!

Comment: what exactly is your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

here you are the solution:

```
<controls:Pivot Title="My Pivot">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding EuropePivotSelectedCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>

<controls:PivotItem Header="item1">
</controls:PivotItem>

<controls:PivotItem Header="item2">
</controls:PivotItem>
```

Regards
Juanlu, ElGuerre